# How to extract tpb files?

Tags: iso, bittorrent

I download a dvd image from torrent, but file extension is iso-tpb.
What should I do with it? :-?

Comment: We're not here to support things you download from ThePirateBay.

Comment: Why is that ? There are legal contents on tpb, you are assuming he is conducting an illegal activity.

Comment: like, about 0.0001%, yes  ;)

Comment: And I somehow doubt legal torrents use obfuscated filename extensions, but who am I...

Comment: I just ask how to extract them, I'm not doing anything illegal... I've just downloaded a dvd image that my friend send to me (in a rar file) when I extract it, there were several *iso-tpb.r#* file. I google it but didn't found anything usefull :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute:

```
file filename.iso-tpb
```

If it's a .iso it will show something like:

```
ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data
```

Answer (score 2):

iso-tpb?... Most probably somebody might have renamed the file. Just rename it back to iso.